# Editing a PHP Page?

Tags: php

I want to make a script, which could automatic edit a PHP file.
For example, in PHP file **abc.php** I have this script

```
<?php
/* 
Data : 'Valid Data'
Method : 'Yes'
*/
?>
```

And I want that, when I get data to a page via **$_GET** or **$_POST** on another page **data.php**, then **abc.php** file will get edited with new **Data**. Identity for replacing the old value in **abc.php** is **single colon** ***(Data : 'Valid Data')***.

I have already tried http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/simple-php-file-editor/, but it doesn't provide any way to use it in my situation.

Comment: Aside from all the security risks, what stops you from creating the PHP file using `fopen`/`fwrite`?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you want to save the data within an array to a PHP document. Is this correct?

Comment: As @Laurent said, you'll have to do file operations with `fopen` et al.  Once you've read in the file, you'll have to parse it like a string essentially, modify it as needed and then write it back with `fwrite`.  If not that, something quite similar.

Comment: @Jonathan: No, array isn't compulsory. I just want to save data from another page in place of **Valid Data**, which is under semicolons on 3rd line of **abc.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Read the text of abc.php into an array, one line per entry
$lines = file('abc.php');

//Replace the third line with the new text, including your new data
$lines[2] = "Data : '" . $some_data . "'\n";

//Write the new lines into abc.php
file_put_contents('abc.php', implode($lines));
```

- http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php
- http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
- http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php